# Unable to click, select or move QGraphicsEllipseItem

Tags: python, qt, pyside6, pyqt6

A small snippet I am using to understand QGraphicsEllipseItem. From my understanding , based on the flags set I should be able to move and capture mouse events but am unable to do so. Any help or guidance ?

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QPoint, QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsEllipseItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent,
    QGraphicsView,
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QWidget,
)


class Icon(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(None)

        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def rect(self) -> QRectF:
        return QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QPoint(48, 48))

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        return QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QPoint(48, 48))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent) -> None:
        print("mousePressEvent")
        return super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget: QWidget) -> None:
        outlinePath = QPainterPath()
        outlinePath.addEllipse(self.boundingRect())
        painter.drawPath(outlinePath.simplified())
        return super().paint(painter, option, widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 400, 200)

    c1 = Icon()
    scene.addItem(c1)
    c1.setPos(200, 100)

    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()
    app.exec()
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `rect` method making the position static and unmovable.  See also Musicmante's comment below for a better understanding of the reason why.....

Just set the rect using `setRect` and don't overwrite those methods and you should receive the mouse events and be able to move it then.

```py
class Icon(QGraphicsEllipseItem):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(None)
        self.setRect(QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QPoint(48, 48)))
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        return QRectF(QPoint(0, 0), QPoint(48, 48))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent) -> None:
        print("mousePressEvent")
        return super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget: QWidget) -> None:
        outlinePath = QPainterPath()
        outlinePath.addEllipse(self.boundingRect())
        painter.drawPath(outlinePath.simplified())
        return super().paint(painter, option, widget)
```

Comment: That's not "exactly" the reason for not being able to move the item: `rect()` is not virtual, so overriding it is useless (unless explicitly called from Python). The *real* reason is that the ellipse has an invalid rect set, and [`shape()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsellipseitem.html#shape) uses the actual rect (not `self.rect()`) of the item for the mouse collision. In fact, overriding `shape()` and returning a QPainterPath with the ellipse based on the boundingRect makes the item movable. But, at that point, all that would make subclassing QGraphicsEllipseItem almost useless.